# Using an operator in place of a function

Tags: go

Is it possible to use an operator in place of a function in go?

For example, in the following code is it possible to replace `add` with `+`?

```
package main

import "fmt"

var cur, prev int = 1, 1

func fib(f func(int, int) int) int {
    return f(cur, prev)
}

func main() {
    add := func(x int, y int) int { return x + y };
    fmt.Println(fib(add))
}
```

If it's not possible to use operators as functions, then I would appreciate a link to the documentation clarifying this.

Comment: Most of the time, the documentation for a language states what it *can* do, not what it *can't*. Thus normally, asking for a link to the documentation if a language *can't* do something doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operators are not first-class values in Go (nor most other languages), so no, you cannot pass them as arguments. Notice that even the [Go documentation](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Function_literals) uses a `func(x,y int) int { return x+y }` in its examples.

Also note that the [grammar for operators](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Operators) does not allow any options for an operator without a corresponding expression to operate on.